# Rodar um programa com argumentos internos

Tags: c#, .net, processo

Como é possível criar um `Process`, inciá-lo sem permitir que qualquer usuário possa ver os argumentos?

Ex:

> Executável: MyGame.exe
>
> Argumentos: -userid 0 -userpwd 0

só que sem permitir que pelo gerenciador de tarefas ou outro método seja impossível de saber quais comandos for passado, apenas o programa `MyGame.exe` vai receber.

Comment: Algum motivo para ter tirado a aceitação e votado na pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Isto é impossível. Seria até inseguro poder esconder.

Se as duas aplicações foram suas aí dá para criar outro mecanismo de comunicação que não precisa disto, é até melhor por outras razões.

Comment: Não, eu vi isso num sistema de um anticheat, o usuário iniciava o launcher de um game e o launcher após logar e autenticar, iniciava o anticheat e ele automaticamente iniciava o executável do jogo eu sabia os parâmetros rodava pelo executável direto e funcionava só que pelo anticheat ele não amostrava os argumentos.

Comment: Aí você teria que perguntar para quem fez, mas provavelmente só escondeu superficialmente. Mesmo assim não sei se não é uma comunicação entre aplicações que sabem interagir juntas, aí dá para esconder.